# Google Play Game Services Logcat warning

Tags: java, android, leaderboards, google-play-services

I'm getting the following warning in my LogCat output.  I have implemented Google Play Games Leaderboards which, after some research, it appears this warning is related to....

[image]

I would point out that my app works fine, it's already published and scores have been submitted to the leaderboard, however, I would like to get rid of this warning if I can but I'm honestly unsure why I have it in the first place.

I've read quite a few questions relating to this warning, however in those questions, there were also actual problems with the Play Games Services not working.

My Activity class is extending BaseGameActivity.  Like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, AdListener{

    //And I will then use getGameHelper() to carry out the various calls
    //For example

    getGameHelper().beginUserInitiatedSignIn();

    getGameHelper().reconnectClient();

}
```

The official tutorial, now seems to suggest extending **Activity** and not **BaseGameActivity** and creating a GoogleApiClient object (unless I'm looking in the wrong place).  As I don't have a GoogleApiClient object, I can't access setViewForPopups.

Is this something that I need to worry about and if so, how do I get rid of it?  It's not causing any issues, however, I'm worried by the '*may not work properly in future versions of the API*' part.

Extremely confused, so any help appreicated.

Comment: You can use `getApiClient().setViewForPopups()` in your activity which extends `BaseGameActivity`.

Comment: Hi @free3dom, if I do **getApiClient().** and let Eclipse show me what is available, **setViewForPopups()** isn't in the resulting list.

Comment: Oh right, it was changed a while back. It is now done through the Games object ([see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html)).

Comment: Yeah, I think they changed it in December, that's when the documentation seems to have been updated.  https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init